# Parallel Jenkins pipeline stages are slower than sequential execution

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm working on a Jenkins pipeline that utilizes parallelization. However, I'm facing an issue where the parallel stages seem to slow each other down instead of achieving true parallelism. Here's the code I'm using:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Dependencies') {
      when {
        anyOf {
          branch 'develop';
          branch 'demo';
          branch 'test';
        }
      }
      parallel{
        stage('Cloud Libraries') {
          steps {
            sh "umask 0000;" 
            sh "pip3.8 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements/cloud.txt -t ${WORKSPACE}/layers/cloud_libraries/python/"
          }
        }
        stage('Cellect Data Processing') {
          steps {
            sh "umask 0000;" 
            sh "pip3.8 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements/cellect/data_processing.txt -t ${WORKSPACE}/layers/cellect_data_processing/python/"
          }
        }
        stage('Cellect Warranty Processing') {
          steps {
            sh "umask 0000;" 
            sh "pip3.8 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements/cellect/warranty_processing.txt -t ${WORKSPACE}/layers/cellect_warranty_processing/python/"
          }
        }
        stage('Cellect Data Consumer') {
          steps {
            sh "umask 0000;" 
            sh "pip3.8 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements/cellect/data_consumer.txt -t ${WORKSPACE}/layers/cellect_data_consumer/python/"
          }
        }
        stage('Cellect BESS Control') {
          steps {
            sh "umask 0000;" 
            sh "pip3.8 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements/cellect/bess_control.txt -t ${WORKSPACE}/layers/cellect_bess_control/python/"
          }
        }

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Previously, when the stages were executed sequentially, the individual times were as follows: 15s, 20s, 20s, 7s, 5s. However, after parallelizing them, the times became: 17s, 24s, 49s, 50s, 44s.

Although the overall time for the parallel execution is greater than the sequential execution, I believe it shouldn't be the case. Am I missing something or have a wrong understanding of how parallelization should work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having details about your agents configuration it would be quite hard to guess the reason for this issue.

However my educated guess would be to check if the the hypervisor on which your agents are running is overutilized. Consider the following example:

1. You have a hypervisor with 24 cores, 128GB ram, SSD hard drive which can do 100gbps read/write speed.
2. You have 5 VMs - each allocates 4 cores, 16GB ram and has an allowance of 6gbps read/write.

In the above example if you execute excessive work in one of the VMs the performance of other VMs will not be affected, because each VM has a very specific constraints that are aligned with what the hypervisor can handle. And the hypervisor itself has extra resources available.

Now consider the following:

1. A hypervisor with 24 cores, 64GB ram, SSD hard drive which can do 10gbps read/write speed.
2. 5 VMs - each allocates 4 cores, 12GB ram and has unbound read/write speed.

The hypervisor has very little resources for itself. And each VM is allowed to allocate the entire IO bandwidth your performance across all VMs might be degraded when you execute heavy tasks on just one VM.

If you start an IO intensive tasks with this setup on VMs 1 to 5, each VM will be trying to allocate IO bandwidth as much as possible resulting in very poor overall performance. If the hypervisor has an HDD instead of SSD, this problem becomes even more obvious and extrapolated.

Same theory applies if you are running Docker containers.

Since you appear to be installing `pip` packages without using cache (`pip3.8 install --no-cache-dir`) this might be creating intensive IO operations, because python might be fetching packages and also doing compilation. Hence you could be getting into what I've described above.

Or, your agents allow for multiple jobs to run on the same agent -- again resulting in exhausting the resources of the agent.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, I am very new to this thing so I also cant say much about agents. I suppose there is agent implementation lacking or smth like this? The machine itself is AWS EC2, it does not have much specifications I suppose.

Comment: I don't think it's an implementation issue - it's most likely misconfiguration that leads to overutilization on some level. Check if the job is using the same agent or spreading across multiple agents. For example - if an agent is configured to have more than ONE executor when you start parallel tasks they might end up executing on the same agent causing high IO.

Comment: if I am understanding it correctly, node is an agent with different numbers of executors, right now when I am checking the nodes in jenkins I have just one with 8 executors. That one node is built-in node  I am sorry if I am saying something incorrectly because I am new as I mentioned.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. One physical agent (node) can have multiple executors. And you can have also multiple agents/nodes. The best practice is to have one agent with one executor and just scale the number of agents. So if you have EC2 instances - you would scale the number of EC2 instances. That will join more agent/nodes into Jenkins and thus you would be physically running your parallel on **separate** agents (and respectfully separate machines).

Comment: Since your agent has 8 executors - that means all of your parallel jobs are being executed on the same physical machine. So you are probably experiencing resource exhaustion, because Jenkins will not do any resource management. Each job gets as much resources at it can. :)